# Scraping a specific website

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping

I'm working on a Python project that includes trying to scrape historical sports odds/results from the site oddsportal.com, for example at the exact URL http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league/results/

The problem is that the actual odds are not embedded in the HTML but obscured by gigantic Javascript. I am aware that a possible approach is to use a headless web driver that can interpret javascript and to pull the data that way, but the website loads tons of extraneous stuff that makes this approach not efficient, so I would appreciate some help in reverse engineering the source of the values.

Some info:

The above HTML loads an extremely large globals-....js file as well as other js and css files (that don't seem to be too relevant) from rb.oddsportal.com and fb.oddsportal.com. In addition there is small communication with weblog.livesport.eu at port 2222 which seems suspicious

The general idea seems to be that the html includes for each match in the table an "xeid" value, and for each participant in addition "xoid" and "xodd" values, that are somehow manipulated by the javascript into the plaintext values.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I attempted to use the approach you describe previously, I ended up using a headless browser as I am unfamiliar with javascript and the code was horribly complex.

Comment: Hmm, this site is interesting. I can't see where it is obtaining its data from, but the name of this file (`/x/pushclient-140501181243.js`) suggests to me they are using long-polling to get the data into the grid. I've not had to work with that yet - maybe there are some tools that can capture this data?

Comment: If they're loading the data from the site after the page loads, which is very likely, you don't want to scrape the page at all. You need to mine their API for the data directly, which will probably be XML or JSON. It doesn't make much difference whether they poll, long-poll, push or set up a websocket, you just need to emulate that in your code. You should try inspecting the AJAX traffic in your browser console.

Comment: @PongWizard that's exactly what I need help in doing

Comment: @ctlaltdefeat I don't know if you'll see this comment or remember this question 6 years later, but I'm working on the same problem right now and have figured out how to access the raw JSON data but am unable to figure out how to decode/transform the xoid or xodd values. Did you ever come up with a solution to turn xoid/xodd into plaintext?

Answer (score 1):

I have worked with this site some time ago so here is my Perl code (as you can see all magic is located in **"http://www.oddsportal.com/feed/postmatch/1-1-" . $match->{id} . "-1321390800-1-2.dat"** file):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Modern::Perl;
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use FindBin qw($Bin);
use Getopt::Long;
use DateTime;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;
use Date::Range;
use Date::Simple;
use JSON::PP;

my $config;

my $result = GetOptions(
    "date=s"   => \$config->{date},
    "league=s" => \$config->{league_id},
    "output"   => \$config->{output_format}
);

( $config->{start_date}, $config->{end_date} ) = split /-/, $config->{date};

unless ( $config->{end_date} ) {

    $config->{end_date} = $config->{start_date};
}

$config->{start_date} = format_date( $config->{start_date} );
$config->{end_date}   = format_date( $config->{end_date} );

my $leagues = {

    1 => {
        title => "English Premier League",
        url =>
          "http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league/results/"
    },
    2 => {
        title => "Primera Division",
        url =>
          "http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/spain/primera-division/results/"
    },
    3 => {
        title => "Bundesliga",
        url   => "http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/germany/bundesliga/results/"
    },
    4 => {
        title => "Ligue 1",
        url   => "http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/france/ligue-1/results/",
    },
    5 => {
        title => "Serie A",
        url   => "http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/italy/serie-a/results/",
    },
    6 => {
        title => "Champs League",
        url =>
          "http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/europe/champions-league/results/",
    },
    7 => {
        title => "Europa League",
        url => "http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/europe/europa-league/results/",
    },
};

say $leagues->{ $config->{league_id} }->{title};

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->agent_alias("Windows IE 6");

$mech->get( $leagues->{ $config->{league_id} }->{url} );

my @matches = find_matches( $mech, $config->{start_date}, $config->{end_date} );

foreach my $match (@matches) {

    collect_info($match);
    save_info($match);
}

sleep 1;

sub collect_info {

    my ($match) = shift;

    my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
    $mech->agent_alias("Windows IE 6");

    say "\t\t", "[$match->{match_date}] $match->{title}";

    #$mech->get( $match->{url} );

    parse_match( $match, $mech );
    sleep 1;
}

#http://www.oddsportal.com/feed/postmatch/1-1-827202-1321390800-1-2.dat 1X2
#http://www.oddsportal.com/feed/postmatch/1-1-1382641-1321390800-1-2.dat

#http://www.oddsportal.com/feed/postmatch/1-1-827202-1321390800-2-2.dat
#http://www.oddsportal.com/feed/postmatch/1-1-827202-1321390800-5-2.dat AH
#http://www.oddsportal.com/feed/postmatch/1-1-827202-1321390800-2-2.dat OU
#http://www.oddsportal.com/feed/postmatch/1-1-827202-1321390800-2-2.dat

#http://www.oddsportal.com/feed/postmatch/1-1-827202-1321390800-6-2.dat DNB
#http://www.oddsportal.com/feed/postmatch/1-1-827202-1321390800-12-2.dat EH
#http://www.oddsportal.com/feed/postmatch/1-1-827202-1321390800-4-2.dat DC

sub parse_match {

    my ( $match, $mech ) = @_;

    parse_1x2( $match, $mech );
    parse_ou( $match, $mech );

    $mech->save_content("1x2.dat");

    sleep 1;
}

sub parse_ou {

    my ( $match, $mech ) = @_;
    $mech->get( "http://www.oddsportal.com/feed/postmatch/1-1-"
          . $match->{id}
          . "-1321390800-2-2.dat" );

    $mech->save_content("ou.dat");

    my $json = $mech->content();
    $json =~ s/^-\|-|-\|-$//sg;

    my $data = decode_json $json;

    #1.5
    (
        $match->{"pinnacle_over_1.5_price"},
        $match->{"pinnacle_under_1.5_price"}
      )
      =
      (
        defined $data->{d}->{oddsdata}->{back}->{"E-2-2-0-1.5-0"}->{odds}->{18}
      )
      ? @{ $data->{d}->{oddsdata}->{back}->{"E-2-2-0-1.5-0"}->{odds}->{18} }
      {qw(0 1)}
      : ( "", "" );

    ( $match->{"betfair_over_1.5_price"}, $match->{"betfair_under_1.5_price"} )
      =
      (
        defined $data->{d}->{oddsdata}->{back}->{"E-2-2-0-1.5-0"}->{odds}->{44}
      )
      ? @{ $data->{d}->{oddsdata}->{back}->{"E-2-2-0-1.5-0"}->{odds}->{44} }
      {qw(0 1)}
      : ( "", "" );

    (
        $match->{"betfair_lay_over_1.5_price"},
        $match->{"betfair_lay_under_1.5_price"}
      )
      =
      (
        defined $data->{d}->{oddsdata}->{back}->{"E-2-2-0-1.5-0"}->{odds}->{44}
      )
      ? @{ $data->{d}->{oddsdata}->{back}->{"E-2-2-0-1.5-0"}->{odds}->{44} }
      {qw(0 1)}
      : ( "", "" );

    (
        $match->{average_home_price}, $match->{average_draw_price},
        $match->{average_away_price}, $match->{highest_home},
        $match->{highest_draw},       $match->{highest_away}
      )
      = find_averages_1x2(
        $data->{d}->{oddsdata}->{back}->{"E-2-2-0-1.5-0"}->{odds},
        [
            qw(

              14
              3
              16
              76
              2
              147
              28
              41
              33
              60
              18
              75
              101
              15
              )
        ]
      );

    #2.5

    (
        $match->{"pinnacle_over_2.5_price"},
        $match->{"pinnacle_under_2.5_price"}
      )
      =
      (
        defined $data->{d}->{oddsdata}->{back}->{"E-2-2-0-2.5-0"}->{odds}->{18}
      )
      ? @{ $data->{d}->{oddsdata}->{back}->{"E-2-2-0-2.5-0"}->{odds}->{18} }
      {qw(0 1)}
      : ( "", "" );

    ( $match->{"betfair_over_2.5_price"}, $match->{"betfair_under_2.5_price"} )
      =
      (
        defined $data->{d}->{oddsdata}->{back}->{"E-2-2-0-2.5-0"}->{odds}->{44}
      )
      ? @{ $data->{d}->{oddsdata}->{back}->{"E-2-2-0-2.5-0"}->{odds}->{44} }
      {qw(0 1)}
      : ( "", "" );

    (
        $match->{"pinnacle_over_3.5_price"},
        $match->{"pinnacle_under_3.5_price"}
      )
      =
      (
        defined $data->{d}->{oddsdata}->{back}->{"E-2-2-0-3.5-0"}->{odds}->{18}
      )
      ? @{ $data->{d}->{oddsdata}->{back}->{"E-2-2-0-3.5-0"}->{odds}->{18} }
      {qw(0 1)}
      : ( "", "" );

    ( $match->{"betfair_over_3.5_price"}, $match->{"betfair_under_3.5_price"} )
      =
      (
        defined $data->{d}->{oddsdata}->{back}->{"E-2-2-0-3.5-0"}->{odds}->{44}
      )
      ? @{ $data->{d}->{oddsdata}->{back}->{"E-2-2-0-3.5-0"}->{odds}->{44} }
      {qw(0 1)}
      : ( "", "" );

    sleep 1;
}

sub parse_1x2 {

    my ( $match, $mech ) = @_;
    $mech->get( "http://www.oddsportal.com/feed/postmatch/1-1-"
          . $match->{id}
          . "-1321390800-1-2.dat" );

    my $json = $mech->content();
    $json =~ s/^-\|-|-\|-$//sg;

    my $data = decode_json $json;

    (
        $match->{pinnacle_home_price},
        $match->{pinnacle_draw_price},
        $match->{pinnacle_away_price}
      )
      = @{ $data->{d}->{oddsdata}->{back}->{"E-1-2-0-0-0"}->{odds}->{18} }
      {qw(0 1 2)};

    (
        $match->{average_home_price}, $match->{average_draw_price},
        $match->{average_away_price}, $match->{highest_home},
        $match->{highest_draw},       $match->{highest_away}
      )
      = find_averages_1x2(
        $data->{d}->{oddsdata}->{back}->{"E-1-2-0-0-0"}->{odds},
        [
            qw(

              14
              3
              16
              76
              2
              147
              28
              41
              33
              60
              18
              75
              101
              15
              )
        ]
      );
}

sub find_averages_ou {

    my ( $bookmakers, $ids ) = @_;
    my ( $avg_home,     $avg_draw,     $avg_away );
    my ( $highest_home, $highest_draw, $highest_away );

    my ( $sum_home, $sum_draw, $sum_away, $counter );

    foreach my $id ( @{$ids} ) {

        $sum_home += $bookmakers->{$id}->{0};
        $sum_draw += $bookmakers->{$id}->{1};
        $sum_away += $bookmakers->{$id}->{2};

        unless ( defined $highest_home ) {

            $highest_home = $bookmakers->{$id}->{0};
            $highest_draw = $bookmakers->{$id}->{1};
            $highest_away = $bookmakers->{$id}->{2};
        }
        else {

            if ( $highest_home < $bookmakers->{$id}->{0} ) {

                $highest_home = $bookmakers->{$id}->{0};
            }

            if ( $highest_draw < $bookmakers->{$id}->{1} ) {

                $highest_draw = $bookmakers->{$id}->{1};
            }

            if ( $highest_away < $bookmakers->{$id}->{2} ) {

                $highest_away = $bookmakers->{$id}->{2};
            }
        }

        $counter++;
    }

    $avg_home = $sum_home / $counter;
    $avg_draw = $sum_draw / $counter;
    $avg_away = $sum_away / $counter;

    return (
        sprintf( "%0.2f", $avg_home ),
        sprintf( "%0.2f", $avg_draw ),
        sprintf( "%0.2f", $avg_away ),
        $highest_home, $highest_draw, $highest_away
    );
}


sub find_averages_1x2 {

    my ( $bookmakers, $ids ) = @_;
    my ( $avg_home,     $avg_draw,     $avg_away );
    my ( $highest_home, $highest_draw, $highest_away );

    my ( $sum_home, $sum_draw, $sum_away, $counter );

    foreach my $id ( @{$ids} ) {

        $sum_home += $bookmakers->{$id}->{0};
        $sum_draw += $bookmakers->{$id}->{1};
        $sum_away += $bookmakers->{$id}->{2};

        unless ( defined $highest_home ) {

            $highest_home = $bookmakers->{$id}->{0};
            $highest_draw = $bookmakers->{$id}->{1};
            $highest_away = $bookmakers->{$id}->{2};
        }
        else {

            if ( $highest_home < $bookmakers->{$id}->{0} ) {

                $highest_home = $bookmakers->{$id}->{0};
            }

            if ( $highest_draw < $bookmakers->{$id}->{1} ) {

                $highest_draw = $bookmakers->{$id}->{1};
            }

            if ( $highest_away < $bookmakers->{$id}->{2} ) {

                $highest_away = $bookmakers->{$id}->{2};
            }
        }

        $counter++;
    }

    $avg_home = $sum_home / $counter;
    $avg_draw = $sum_draw / $counter;
    $avg_away = $sum_away / $counter;

    return (
        sprintf( "%0.2f", $avg_home ),
        sprintf( "%0.2f", $avg_draw ),
        sprintf( "%0.2f", $avg_away ),
        $highest_home, $highest_draw, $highest_away
    );
}

sub format_date {

    my ($date) = shift;

    my ( $day, $month, $year ) = $date =~ m{(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})};

    $date = join( "-", $year, $month, $day );

    return $date;
}

sub find_matches {

    my ( $mech, $start_date, $end_date ) = @_;
    my @matches;

    my ( $year, $day, $month ) = split /-/, $start_date;

    my $season;
    if ( $start_date lt $year . "-08-01" ) {

        $season->{title} = join( "/", $year - 1, $year );
    }
    else {

        $season->{title} = join( "/", $year, $year + 1 );
    }

    say "\t", $season->{title};
    $mech->follow_link( text => $season->{title} );

    process_season( $mech, $season );

    my $range = Date::Range->new( Date::Simple->new($start_date),
        Date::Simple->new($end_date) );

    foreach my $date ( $range->dates ) {

        if ( exists $season->{matches}->{$date} ) {

            push @matches, @{ $season->{matches}->{$date} };
        }
    }

    return @matches;
}

sub process_season {

    my ( $mech, $season ) = @_;

    say "\t\tCollecting season info...";

  PARSE_RESULT_PAGE:
    my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_content( $mech->content() );

    my ($current_page) = $tree->findvalues('//span[@class = "active-page"]');
    my ($last_page_url) =
      $tree->findvalues('//div[ @id = "pagination"]/a[ last() ]/@href');
    my ($next_page_url) =
      $tree->findvalues('//div[ @id = "pagination"]/a[ last() -1 ]/@href');
    my ($last_page) = $last_page_url =~ m{/(\d+)/$};

    my $match_day;
    foreach my $row (
        $tree->findnodes('//table[ @id = "tournamentTable" ]/tbody/tr') )
    {

        next
          unless ( ( $row->attr('class') eq "center nob-border" )
            || ( $row->attr('class') =~ m/deactivate/ ) );

        if ( $row->attr('class') eq "center nob-border" ) {

            my ($match_day_string) = $row->findvalues('./th[1]/span');
            $match_day = convert_match_day($match_day_string);
        }
        else {

            my $match = get_match_info($row);
            $match->{match_date} = $match_day;

            ( $match->{home}, $match->{away} ) = split /\s+-\s+/,
              $match->{title};
            ( $match->{home_team_goals}, $match->{away_team_goals} ) =
              split /:/, $match->{score};

            if ($match_day) {

                push @{ $season->{matches}->{$match_day} }, $match;
            }
        }
    }

    while ( $current_page != $last_page ) {

        $mech->get( "http://www.oddsportal.com" . $next_page_url );
        goto PARSE_RESULT_PAGE;
    }

    $tree->delete();
    say "\t\tDone!";
}

sub get_match_info {

    my ($row) = shift;
    my $match;

    ( $match->{start_time} ) = $row->findvalues('./td[1]');
    ( $match->{url} )        = $row->findvalues('./td[2]/a/@href');
    $match->{url} = "http://www.oddsportal.com" . $match->{url};

    ( $match->{id} ) = $match->{url} =~ m{(\d+)/$};

    ( $match->{title} ) = $row->findvalues('./td[2]/a');
    ( $match->{score} ) = $row->findvalues('./td[3]');

    return $match;
}

sub convert_match_day {

    my ($text_date) = shift;

    $text_date =~ s/\s+/ /g;

    my $strp = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
        pattern  => '%d %B %Y',
        locale   => 'en_US',
        on_error => 'croak',
    );

    my $dt = $strp->parse_datetime($text_date);

    if ($dt) {

        return $dt->ymd();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm on my phone at the moment but it seems that the example links commented out give an error and that you collected the match ids by using the browser which perhaps slows it down. Will take a closer look later, thanks!

Comment: The code worked in the March of 2013. Also you're right about match ids but I collected this info via same program (so no browser but I'm using Mechanize for this)

Comment: I wonder if the whole method changed or maybe the IDs are not relevant anymore? Could you walk me through your process of exploring this?

Comment: the global.js file includes this: '/feed/postmatchscore/'+this.params.sportId+'-'+this.eventId+'-'+this.params.xhash+'
I wonder how the xhash is calculated, the js file is too obfuscated for me to able to figure it out

Comment: I have checked current version of the site -- the logic is almost the same, for example http://fb.oddsportal.com/feed/match/1-1-8E37D1dF-1-2-yjea6.dat?_=1399078842020 data URL, 8E37D1dF is the ID of the match (you can find it in the match's HTML), 1-2 is some kind of prefix for different results (see my code)

Comment: `new PageEvent({"id":"8E37D1dF","xhash":"yjea6"` this is from match's HTML

Comment: Yes I got this far, but it is not clear how to calculate the xhash without browsing to the page of every individual match and applying the js, which kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: Not to mention the xhash has since changed for that specific ID, making it even weirder

Comment: I am doing the same thing now, 7 years later. I am managing to scrape only the 1X2 bets, but I need to scrape Over/Under and BTS, I am still trying to decypher this xhash

Comment: I managed to collect all the data I want. I have a working scraper written in Python.

Comment: Hi @IvanDimitrov how did you manage it ? Can you give us working example ?

Comment: Hi @akinKaplanoglu, this is from a long time ago :D. I managed to find how I get the actual relevant data, but I haven't ran this for quite some time now. https://pastebin.com/hYkbCK1W - this is the part where I extract the actual data from the website. o_x_t_data is for the bookie id. o_u_data is over/under, bts_data is both to score/not score.

Comment: @IvanDimitrov TY. How did you get xhash ? Do we need to go to the match page ?

Comment: @ctlaltdefeat did you find the way how to get this xhash without browsing to the page of every match ?

Comment: @akinKaplanoglu I get the xhash from the actual page apparently - 
page_json = json.loads(re.findall(r"PageEvent\(({.*})\)", match_page)[0])